# How to compare two labels and update the gridview accordingly? ASP.NET GRIDVIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview that looks like this:

[image]

Currently there are values in "Actual", "Target_Amt" and "Month" - which all are Templatefield and "MetGoal" which is empty for now.

I want to achieve smth like this:
if 'Actual' value is LESS THAN 'Target_Amt', I want to update the column "MetGoal" to 'Y'
else, it would be 'N'

** **Y - Yes, N - No**

***any ideas of how i can do to achieve this?***

My gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actual">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Actual") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Actual") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target_Amt">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Target_Amt") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Target_Amt") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" HeaderText="Month" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MetGoal">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wxNj.png)

Current code now:

```
<%# Convert.ToInt32(Bind("Actual")) < Convert.ToInt32(Bind("Target_Amt")) ? "Y" : "N" %>
```

Comment: `<%# Convert.ToInt32(Bind("Actual")) < Convert.ToInt32(Bind("Target_Amt")) ? "Y" : "N" %>`

Comment: Where should I put that line of code at? Do I need to create a new method or use any existing gridview action or something? @VDWWD

Comment: In the `ItemTemplate` of column MetGoal

Comment: Ok I tried. It's been giving a compilation error, Updated in the question. @VDWWD

Comment: You don;t need the label, just put it in the itemtemplate

Comment: I removed the label and put the above code. It still returns a compilation error: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context @VDWWD

Comment: Try `Eval` instead of `Bind`

Comment: @VDWWD, hello. I was wondering if there is any other alternative method in achieving this? Because I need to store the value (y/n) into my database

Comment: Why would you need to store it? If Actual and Target_Amt are in the same database you can always calculate that column on the fly. If you store it you need to always update those 2 columns and the y/n column